# Does a symbol have to be unique in ERC721? How to find out a unique symbol?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

As per the ERC-721 contract on OpenZeppelin, you can create a token with this constructor:

```
constructor(string _name, string _symbol) public {}
```

Does the "_symbol" have to be unique across the blockchain? If yes, then how can one find a unique public _symbol? Is there a public register maintained?

If it doesn't have to be unique, then a duplication of a contract with the same name and symbol, won't it confuse the people searching for your _symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the symbol have to be unique across the blockchain?

No, the only thing which needs to be unique is the contract address.

> If it doesn't have to be unique, then won't it confuse the people searching for your symbol?

Yes, that's why it is in your interest to choose a unique name and a unique symbol.